# WSO2is SCIM2 filter Enterprise attributers

Tags: scim2, wso2-identity-server

I try to filter users in base to a certain attribute, I found an example to do this:

```
https://identity.sample.com/t/tenantname.com/scim2/Users?filter=EnterpriseUser.organization+Eq+WSO2
```

When I run the previos query, this is the result:

```sh
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:Error"
    ],
    "scimType": "invalidValue",
    "detail": "Not a valid attribute name/uri",
    "status": "400"
}
```

The result for a filter using ID, is this:

```js
"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User": {
                "organization": "WSO2"               
 }
```

Comment: What's the IS version?

Comment: The version is WSO2is 5.10, thank you!

Comment: For the moment stick to the below filer. Will check what went wrong. `filter=urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:organization+Eq+WSO2`

Comment: Ok, thank you a lot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by Nipun Thathsara above you should be using a filter like below.

```
https://identity.sample.com/t/tenantname.com/scim2/Users?filter=urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User:organization+Eq+WSO2
```

This was done to resolve spec compliance [issue](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/3487).